# How to get macOS app's resource usage during a time period?

Tags: macos

We can use the Activity app to see an app's CPU and memory's real time usage, I was wondering if maybe we could get the resource consumption graph during a time period?

Or if there're some system command for us to get the process info?  In that case we could get information repeatedly and create graphs by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options at first glance here. First, there's the `sar` command. Run `man sar` to see the options. A basic example is

```
sar -o ~/datadump.sar 50 100
```

This will dump 50 different measurements at an interval of 100 seconds.

There is also a program called Syrupy, in Python. Check it out [here](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/Syrupy).

If you want to look at something low level (well closer to the system I suppose), then you can use `top`, which is what activity monitor is built on. Pipe the data from it to `grep` or `awk`. Useful reference is [here](http://ss64.com/osx/top.html)

Comment: Great! Syrupy works well for me.